# Beamer: change gray out on itemize environment

Tags: beamer, lists, enumerate, itemize, description

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Beamer: double uncover hides instead of watermarks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52061/beamer-double-uncover-hides-instead-of-watermarks)

This is a following up question to the solution for this question:
[Beamer: double uncover hides instead of watermarks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52061/beamer-double-uncover-hides-instead-of-watermarks)

I'd like to know, how I have to change the code for the `enumerate` environment

```
\makeatletter
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{enumerate}{\ifnum\@enumdepth=1 
  \only<1->{\setbeamercovered{transparent=100}}%
  \only<\theenumi->{\setbeamercovered{transparent=15}}%
\fi
}
\makeatother
```

to get the same for the `itemize` and `description` environment. Some trials from myself end in errors...

Comment: Did you try my solution to that question? `:-)`

Comment: Shortly after I suggested you to open a a new follow-up question, @HendrikVogt wrote his answer (which does exactly what you need).

Comment: Das habe ich wirklich nicht gesehen. Funktioniert wunderbar! Danke!