# Beamer - Nested uncover hides instead of watermark

Tags: beamer, transparency, uncover

I am preparing a presentation using beamer and there is an old problem I would like to solve.

If I nest two `\uncover` commands then the content of the inner one is so dim that it appears hidden from the slide until the outer one becomes visible.

I would like to avoid this and having just one level of transparency. Does anybody have something to suggest?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Pittsburgh}
\usecolortheme{crane}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    Hello!
    \uncover<2->{
    \begin{theorem}
        Hello world!
        \uncover<3->{Goodbye!}
    \end{theorem}
    }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

PS: I don't think this is a duplicate of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52061/beamer-double-uncover-hides-instead-of-watermarks), because the situation here seems different to me, but I am not an expert.

Comment: Thanks @Denis, but that is not exactly what I would like to obtain. I still would like to see in transparency what is going to come, in order to leave the people to know what to expect. Do you have any other solution to suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply don't uncover the "Goodbye!" on the first slide:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Pittsburgh}
\usecolortheme{crane}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    Hello!
    \uncover<2->{
    \begin{theorem}
        Hello world!
        \uncover<1,3->{Goodbye!}
    \end{theorem}
    }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @samcarter, but it does not seem to work if the `\uncover` are not linearly nested. For example it creates a "disco-effect" in this case:
`\begin{frame}
 Hello!
 \uncover<2->{
 \begin{theorem}
  Hello world!
  \uncover<3->{Goodbye!}
 \end{theorem}
 \uncover<4->{Farewell!}
 }
\end{frame}`

Comment: @EnderWiggins Please see my edit

Comment: Chapeau: it works perfectly and that's the easiest solution one may consider.